# what is the best approach to call rest api from nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, promise

I have a node-rest-client that i am using to make post call to external application, Below call is returning 400 and i also see the response from server but task is not being completed.

1- what is the best approach to make api call from nodejs ?

2- How to use promise for rest client module ?

restCall.js

```
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
var client = new Client();

var arg2 = {
    data: {"workerId":"aworkerId",
           "variables":{
           "caseIdFound":{"value": true}
           }
     }
}

//Complete Task
function completeTask(taskId) {
    client.post('https/url/'+taskId+'/complete',arg2,function(data,response) {
        console.log('CompleteTaskResponse',data);
        console.log('ResponseComplete',response.body);
    })
}

completeTask(3455l);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with the `node-rest-client` module but a few things stick out to me.

Where is the error parameter in your callback? Usually you should be able to do something like

`post('yourUrl', data, (error, data) => { 
  ...
})`

That way you can look at the error response and see what's going wrong. Personally I would recommend using the library [needle](https://github.com/tomas/needle) if not the `http` module itself.

To use promises with this, you could try and promisify the library. Not sure if this library supports that but with a library like [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) you could do

`Promise.promisifyAll(nodeClient)`

Alternatively you can wrap the calls in your own function as follows

```
function post (url, data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
    client.post(url, data, (error, response) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error)
      } else {
        resolve(response.body)  
      }
    }      
  })
}
```

Then you can do stuff like

```
post(myUrl, { ... })
  .then((info) => { ... })
  .catch((error) => { ... })
```